# How to request focus synchronously in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, focus, awt, keyboardfocusmanager

When I call `component.requestFocusInWindow()`, Swing enqueues asynchronous `FOCUS_GAINED` and `FOCUS_LOST` events rather than synchronously transferring focus. As a workaround, it appears that `DefaultKeyboardFocusManager` is trying to *simulate* synchronously switching focus by delaying the dispatch of keyboard events until focus events have finished dispatching. But it appears that this isn’t working properly.

Question: Is there any way to change focus synchronously in Swing? Is `DefaultKeyboardFocusManager` really trying to simulate synchronous focus, and is it seriously buggy? Is there a focus manager that does this correctly?

Motivation: I have a `JTextField` that automatically transfers focus when it’s full. In writing integration tests using `java.awt.Robot`, I need its behavior to be deterministic and not timing-dependent.

Related question that didn’t get much response: [How to grab focus *now*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389335/swing-how-to-grab-focus-now)

Here’s a demo. Expected behavior: when you hold down a key, each `JTextField` will contain a single character. Actual behavior: focus does not change fast enough so they get multiple characters.

**Update**: Note that this behavior is not specific to progammatically changing focus. In the third example, I took out the custom focus calls and instead simply set the document update delay to 500ms. Then I typed <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>7</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>. As you can see, the digits are queued properly but the tab presses get dropped.

[image: Screenshot]
[image: Screenshot after holding down 1 button]
[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Group;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

public class AwtEventListenerDemo {
    public static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AwtEventListenerDemo.class.getName());
    private static String keyEventToString(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        int id = keyEvent.getID();
        String eventName =
            id == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED ? "key_pressed" :
            id == KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED ? "key_typed" :
            id == KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED? "key_released" : "unknown " + id;
        String what = id == KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED ? "" + keyEvent.getKeyChar() : "#" + keyEvent.getKeyCode();
        String componentString = keyEvent.getComponent().getName();
        if (componentString == null) componentString = keyEvent.getComponent().toString();
        return String.format("%12s %4s on %s", eventName, what, componentString);
    }
    private static String focusEventToString(FocusEvent focusEvent) {
        int id = focusEvent.getID();
        String eventName = id == FocusEvent.FOCUS_GAINED ? "focus_gained" :
            id == FocusEvent.FOCUS_LOST ? "focus_lost" :
                null;
        if (eventName == null) return focusEvent.toString();
        String componentString = focusEvent.getComponent().getName();
        if (componentString == null) componentString = focusEvent.getComponent().toString();
        return String.format("%12s on %s", eventName, componentString);
    }
    private final AWTEventListener loggingListener = new AWTEventListener() {
        @Override public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
            if (event instanceof KeyEvent) {
                KeyEvent keyEvent = (KeyEvent) event;
                int id = keyEvent.getID();
                if (id == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED && keyEvent.getComponent() instanceof JTextField && ((JTextField)keyEvent.getComponent()).getDocument().getLength() == 1) {
                    EventQueue eventQueue = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue();
                    ArrayList<AWTEvent> inQueue = new ArrayList<AWTEvent>();
                    int[] interestingIds = new int[] {KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, FocusEvent.FOCUS_GAINED, FocusEvent.FOCUS_LOST};
                    for (int i: interestingIds) {
                        AWTEvent peek = eventQueue.peekEvent(i);
                        if (peek != null)
                            inQueue.add(peek);
                    }
                    ArrayList<String> inQueueString = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (AWTEvent peek: inQueue) {
                        if (peek instanceof KeyEvent) {
                            inQueueString.add(keyEventToString((KeyEvent) peek));
                        } else if (peek instanceof FocusEvent) {
                            inQueueString.add(focusEventToString((FocusEvent) peek));
                        }
                    }

                    logger.info(String.format("Still in the queue (in no particular order): %s", inQueueString));
                }
                logger.info(keyEventToString(keyEvent));
            } else {
                logger.info(event.toString());
            }
        }
    };
    private JFrame jframe;

    public void init() {
        long mask = AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK;  //  AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK | 
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(loggingListener, mask);
        if (jframe == null) jframe = new JFrame(AwtEventListenerDemo.class.getSimpleName());
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                initUI();
            }
        });
    }
    public void cleanupForRestart() {
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().removeAWTEventListener(loggingListener);
    }
    public void destroy() {
        cleanupForRestart();
        jframe.setVisible(false);
        jframe = null;
    }

    public void initUI() {
        GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(jframe.getContentPane());
        jframe.getContentPane().removeAll();
        jframe.getContentPane().setLayout(groupLayout);

        JButton jbutton = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Restart") {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                cleanupForRestart();
                init();
            }
        });
        groupLayout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
        groupLayout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);
        Group verticalGroup = groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jbutton);
        Group horizontalGroup = groupLayout.createParallelGroup()
                .addComponent(jbutton);
        groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(verticalGroup);
        groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(horizontalGroup);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            final JTextField jtextfield = new JTextField();
            jtextfield.setName(String.format("JTextField %d", i));
            verticalGroup.addComponent(jtextfield);
            horizontalGroup.addComponent(jtextfield);
            boolean useDocumentListener = true;
            final boolean useFocusRootAncestor = false;
            if (useDocumentListener) {
                DocumentListener listener = new DocumentListener() {
                    @Override public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) { }
                    @Override public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

                        // Simulate a slow event listener. When the listener is
                        // slow, the problems get worse.
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(50);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                            logger.warning(e1.toString());
                        }
                        if (e.getDocument().getLength() > 0) {
                            // These two methods of transferring focus appear
                            // equivalent.
                            if (useFocusRootAncestor) {
                                Container focusRoot = jtextfield.getFocusCycleRootAncestor();
                                FocusTraversalPolicy policy = focusRoot.getFocusTraversalPolicy();
                                Component nextComponent = policy.getComponentAfter(focusRoot, jtextfield);
                                nextComponent.requestFocusInWindow();
                            } else {
                                KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().focusNextComponent(jtextfield);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    @Override public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) { }
                };
                jtextfield.getDocument().addDocumentListener(listener);
            }
        }

        if (!jframe.isVisible()) {
            jframe.pack();
            jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            jframe.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        // Use a single-line console log handler.
        LogManager.getLogManager().reset();
        Formatter formatter = new Formatter() {
            private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm:ss.SSS");
            @Override
            public String format(LogRecord logRecord) {
                Date date = new Date(logRecord.getMillis());
                DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(date);
                return String.format("%s %s %s %s%n",
                        dateFormat.format(date),
                        logRecord.getLoggerName(),
                        logRecord.getLevel(),
                        logRecord.getMessage());
            }
        };
        ConsoleHandler consoleHandler = new ConsoleHandler();
        consoleHandler.setFormatter(formatter);
        consoleHandler.setLevel(Level.FINEST);
        logger.addHandler(consoleHandler);
        Logger focusLogger = Logger.getLogger("java.awt.focus.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager");
        focusLogger.setLevel(Level.FINEST);
        focusLogger.addHandler(consoleHandler);


        final AwtEventListenerDemo demo = new AwtEventListenerDemo();
        demo.init();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

yes, `Focus` is pretty asynchronous, then should be wrapped int invokeLater, no way

EDIT

[and nice workaround by @camickr](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/dialog-focus/)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
//http://www.coderanch.com/t/342205/GUI/java/Tab-order-swing-components
public class Testing {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Component[] focusList;
    private int focusNumber = 0;
    private JFrame frame;

    public Testing() {
        JTextField tf1 = new JTextField(5);
        JTextField tf2 = new JTextField(5);
        JTextField tf3 = new JTextField(5);
        JButton b1 = new JButton("B1");
        JButton b2 = new JButton("B2");
        tf2.setEnabled(false);
        focusList = new Component[]{tf1, b1, tf2, b2, tf3};
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 1));
        panel.add(tf1);
        panel.add(b1);
        panel.add(tf2);
        panel.add(b2);
        panel.add(tf3);
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setFocusTraversalPolicy(new MyFocusTraversalPolicy());
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocation(150, 100);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(new KeyEventDispatcher() {

            public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent ke) {
                if (ke.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED) {
                    if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_TAB) {
                        Component comp = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().getFocusOwner();
                        if (comp.isEnabled() == false) {
                            if (ke.isShiftDown()) {
                                KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().focusPreviousComponent();
                            } else {
                                KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().focusNextComponent();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private class MyFocusTraversalPolicy extends FocusTraversalPolicy {

        public Component getComponentAfter(Container focusCycleRoot, Component aComponent) {
            focusNumber = (focusNumber + 1) % focusList.length;
            return focusList[focusNumber];
        }

        public Component getComponentBefore(Container focusCycleRoot, Component aComponent) {
            focusNumber = (focusList.length + focusNumber - 1) % focusList.length;
            return focusList[focusNumber];
        }

        public Component getDefaultComponent(Container focusCycleRoot) {
            return focusList[0];
        }

        public Component getLastComponent(Container focusCycleRoot) {
            return focusList[focusList.length - 1];
        }

        public Component getFirstComponent(Container focusCycleRoot) {
            return focusList[0];
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Testing testing = new Testing();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 I kept looking at this question thinking Rob's 'dialog focus' but had not had time to reply.

Comment: I’m afraid I don’t understand mKorbel’s answer. What does “then should be wrapped int invokeLater, no way” mean? The linked article by @camickr’s teaches how to `requestFocusInWindow` after `setVisible` of a modal dialog. And the code sample shows how to skip a disabled component. But none of them address the underlying problem, which is that `requestFocusInWindow` (sometimes) fails to change focus before the already enqueued key events are dispatched.